# cant read Properties from another module

Tags: spring, module, properties, javabeans

I'm creating a project which is on two modules: service and web

in service i'am injecting beans with properties defined in web module. properties depends on profiles defined in web module.

at jetty start a spring errors have been displayed informing me that he can't read properties so he can't instanciate beans.

So how to declare properties in web module and use them in service module?

in service module I'am injecting a bean which uses properties declared in another module

```
<bean id="universignService" 
class="fr.lfm.dna.service.file.document.impl.UniversignServiceImpl"
    autowire="byName" init-method="initWebService" lazy-init="true">
<property name="url" value="${ws.universign.url}">
</property>
<property name="username" value="${dna.ws.universign.username}">
</property>
<property name="password" value="${dna.ws.universign.password}">
</property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Could you clarifiy, what do you mean by "modules"? I assume that you mean Intellij IDEA project modules. Anyway, you should provide a code, where your properties are injected into beans.

Comment: It's a maven eclipse project.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I understand, you have 2(ServiceProject and WebProject) maven projects. In ServiceProject you want to use propeties from WebProject/pom.xml. The thing is Spring doesn't know anything about this file.

There are few options, if you want to share these properties for multiple projects.

1) The first that comes to my mind is to create a parent maven-project. It's going to be a project with just one pom.xml, where you can define your properties in `properties` section.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <dna.ws.universign.username>ABC</dna.ws.universign.username>
        <dna.ws.universign.password>XYZ</dna.ws.universign.password>
    </properties>
</project>
```

After you do this, you can refer to this project in other projects.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>web</artifactId>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent
</project>
```

As a result, properties from you parent project are included in your actual project (com.tests.web in my example).

2) Speaking of storing an username and a password, it might be more convenient and more natural to store them in an external *.properties file. In this case you don't need to create a parent project. Try to take a look at `maven-properies-plugin`.

Whether way you chose, after your properties are defined on maven-level, you should pass it to spring config. In case you use xml-configuration (like in your post), you should ask maven to process files with such `${...}` placeholders. Just put this xml in your pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>spring-config.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
```

Where `spring-config.xml` is a file, where you store your configuration. After this, properties can be injected by Spring.

Comment: The problem is even properties depend on runtime environment: dev, prod. so it must be in filtred properties files outside pom.xml

Comment: I'm wondering, if you're using Spring Boot in this project? If so, than things would be much easier.